# How to display MKSnapshot in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to take a snapshot of the street view of a location pinned in my app using MKSnapshotter. I currently have this code:

```
var options: MKMapSnapshotOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions();
    options.region = self.attractionDetailMap.region;
    options.size = self.attractionDetailMap.frame.size;
    options.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;

    var fileURL:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "path/to/snapshot.png")!;
    var snapshotter:MKMapSnapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter();
    snapshotter.startWithCompletionHandler { (snapshot:MKMapSnapshot!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if(error != nil) {
            println("error: " + error.localizedDescription);
            return;
        }
        let image:UIImage = snapshot.image;
        var data:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        data.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true);

        var pin:MKAnnotationView = MKAnnotationView();
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, true, image.scale);
        image.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0));
        var rect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        for annotation in self.attractionDetailMap.annotations as! [MKAnnotation]{
            var point:CGPoint = snapshot.pointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
            if(CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)) {
                point.x = point.x + pin.centerOffset.x - (pin.bounds.size.width / 2.0);
                point.y = point.y + pin.centerOffset.y - (pin.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
                pin.image.drawAtPoint(point);
            }
        }

        var compositeImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        var data2:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(compositeImage);
        data.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true);
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now that I have the image, I don't know how to actually display the snapshot to my mapview.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So the MKMapSnapshotter class isn't used to display inside of a mapview. It only returns the image of a map that isn't compatible with a mapview. I have used it when I need extra performance like displaying a map with pin in a tableview cell or collectionview. It performs way better than displaying an actual mapview inside of a tableview.

So once you have your snapshot all you do is load it in a UIImageView. It looks just like the mapview would.